# react, typescript Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to using typescript with react.  I'm trying to handle the onClick event of a list item and I get the error "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent'." I'm calling a function to handle click event but it doesn't work.  I'm not sure how to properly do it. Below is the code I'm using to try to accomplish this.

```
function onClick(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
setActiveSuggestion(0);
setFilteredSuggestions([]);
setShowSuggestions(false);
setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value);

};

let suggestionsListComponent;

if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
  if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
    suggestionsListComponent = (
      <ul className="suggestions">
        {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
          let className;

          // Flag the active suggestion with a class
          if (index === activeSuggestion) {
            className = "suggestion-active";
          }

          return (
            <li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={() => onClick(activeSuggestion)}>
              {suggestion}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  } else {
    suggestionsListComponent = (
      <div className="no-suggestions">
        <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're passing a number to your `onClick` function when it expects an event, at `onClick(activeSuggestion)`. `activeSuggestion` is a number.

Answer (score 2):

The function is expecting an event object:

```
function onClick(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
```

You're passing it a number:

```
onClick={() => onClick(activeSuggestion)}
```

The event type doesn't make sense for an `<li>` element, which is neither an input nor has a change event.  It looks like you just want to expect a number:

```
function onClick(value: Number) {
```

And that, within the function, your intent is to set a state value to that number:

```
setUserInput(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass this way on element itself `onClick={(e) => onClick(e,activeSuggestion)}`
and on onClick method definition receive (e,param) two parameters;

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after @David post. I changed the following function parameter to a string and then passed the suggestion string to it and it worked.

```
function onClick(suggestion: string)

<li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={() => onClick(suggestion)}>
          {suggestion}
        </li>
```